# How to get FB AD account name via Python API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Am trying to get a list of ad accounts in my business manager in the form of:

```
<Ad Account id; Ad Account name>
```

This is how a get the list of ad accounts:

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)
me = AdUser(fbid='me')
my_account_first=me.get_ad_accounts()[0]

>>>print my_account_first
<AdAccount> {
    "account_id": "1654219XXXXXXX",
    "id":

type(my_account_first)
<class 'facebookads.objects.AdAccount'>
```

Here is the class definition:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/blob/master/facebookads/objects.py#L964

Could anyone advise how to extract FB Ad account name once I have the account ID? 
It seems like an obvious task, but can not find the respective API method/field.

Thank You in adavance for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which fields are present in the response, by setting the `fields` parameter in the `get_ad_accounts` call.

```
my_account_first=me.get_ad_accounts(fields=[AdAccount.Field.name])[0]
```

The SDK repo has a lot of good examples for different use cases: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/tree/master/examples